# Strategy for creating index partitions in lucene

Tags: lucene

What is the best index partition strategy for faster searches in lucene?

Are fewer index partitions better and results in faster searches than many index partitions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, I think it is important to emphasize the difference between *partitioning* and *sharding*.

As I understand, **partitioning** in Lucene would mean that you have multiple indices (separate `IndexReader`s / `IndexWriter`s / `Directory` instances) but all would be running under the same JVM.

**Sharding** would imply everything mentioned above **plus** separate JVM (would also make sense to place indices on different disks if you are disk-bound).

Anyway, there is no simple answer to this, but these are some general points:

**Pros**:

- Faster indexing (can be done in parallel) -- both for sharding and partitioning
- Faster searching (query computations can be done in parallel) -- both for sharding and partitioning
- Smaller index usually means less GC overhead and more predictability -- sharding only
- Smaller index increases chances of data fitting in OS cache -- sharding only

More points [here](http://www.slideshare.net/thelabdude/tjp-solr-webinar).

**Cons**:

- Added complexity -- both
- Added maintenance costs -- sharding only
- I don't think [grouping and joining](http://www.slideshare.net/lucenerevolution/grouping-and-joining-in-lucenesolr) would be possible across shards

Above said, I'd only recommend sharding if you are struggling with performance or plan significant data influx in the future. Partitioning generally is a good idea if the data is separated logically; you could use it as a first step towards sharding (if you decide so).